# How to determine the number of digits of a number in a table

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-table

I am trying to determine the number of digits of a number in a table. For example if I have a table like this:

```
   4    200   50  1236
  69     54  285     1
1458      2   69   555
```

The answer would be

```
1 3 2 4
2 2 3 1 
4 1 2 3
```

I used to be able to do this with this code

```
strlength(num2str(ADCPCRUM2(i,2)))
```

but then my input was numeric, and not a table.

How do I determine the length of a number in a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`floor(log10(A))` does this. [`log10()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log10.html) basically counts the number of digits before/behind the decimal separator where the most significant number is.

When using this on a table, a simple call to [`table2array()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2array.html) should solve it.

*Caveat:* this only works for integers; for non-integer inputs it would get a lot more involved.